# Adding columns and sub columns in ExtJs 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, web-applications, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to add some column header groups with sub columns in ExtJs, however I am having some difficulty...

I know that when we specify the config for a gridpanel, we can use a tree like structure to specify columns with sub groups i.e.

```
columns[{
  text: 'column1',
  columns[{
      text: 'subcolumn'
  }]
}}
```

This is fine, however, I am trying to do this dynamically when my gridpanel store loads

I have some code which creates a grid column on the fly

```
   retCol = new Ext.grid.column.Column({
       fixed: false,
       hideable: false,
       menuDisabled: true,
       draggable: false,
       sortable: false,
       align: 'center',               
       text: monthName,
       columns: []
   });
```

The problem is, the newly created doesn't seem to have the value for columns that I supplied, it is hidden away in the initialConfig but it is of no use there :-/

Seen as this code creates the column header, if we don't have an array of columns, there is no way of adding sub columns. I tried adding to the 'items' config, but that doesn't work either :-/

Thanks for any help in Advance

Baz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add columns after the grid has been rendered you can use the grid [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) method.

I just read your question again, the reconfigure will also expect you the give your column config in the structure you posted. Not with the dynamically created headers.

You can build your column config dynamically though, after your store has loaded and pass the new config through reconfigure to your grid.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, build the config dynamically. But after I have created my column, there is no array of columns belonging to it which I can add sub columns.

Comment: No but you can build something like `columns: [{dataIndex: test, columns: [...] } ]` dynamically aswell, you don't have to do it with full classes.

Comment: Building the column config dynamically worked :) I used  a simple array of objects to do the trick!! Thanks Johan!!!